# jquery function to empty some elements in a form

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a form, I'd like with a button have reset button effect only on input text inside a div here is an extraxt of my code:

html:

```
<div id="new_prom" style="clear:both; padding:2px; border:1px solid red; margin:5px;">
<div>
  Codice <input type="text" id="cod_pro" name="cod_pro" class="short"> Sottocodice <input type="text" id="sotto_pro" name="sotto_pro" class="short"><br>
Nominativo<br>
<input type="text" id="nom_pro" name="nom_pro" class="long">
</div>
<div>
<div class="bt" id="bt_pro">INSERISCI</div> <div class="bt" id="resetta">RESET</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#resetta").live('click', function()
{
   $("#new_prom > text").each(function(){$(this).val("")});
});
```

thanks in advance.

ciao, h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it correct, the selector is [`[type='text']`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or [`:text`](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/), like this:

```
$("#resetta").live('click', function() {
  $("#new_prom :text").val("");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/NZjjR/), the other part is the [`.val("")`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), it'll work on all matched elements when setting, no need to loop in a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Thanks to Nick Craver and Spinon that's working code for me:

$("#resetta").live('click', function()  
 {  
    $("#new_prom :text").each(function(){$(this).val("")});  
 });

Answer (score 1):

Think you forgot the colon.

```
$("#resetta").live('click', function() 
{ 
   $("#new_prom :text").each(function(){$(this).val("")}); 
});
```

Comment: I have tryed your code but not work in my case :( I've to say for understand better my problem that html and jquery codes are not in the same page

Comment: Yeah as @Nick mentioned I missed that the text elements are not direct children and didn't notice you had that. I was just fixing the text selector. So you need to remove the > sign like in my edit.